# Feed output from a function into nested foreach loop in R

Tags: r, loops, foreach, nested

I wish to create a nested foreach loop such that the outer loop carries out a function and feeds this output into the nested foreach loop. I want to %dopar% for only the inner loop and the output should be a column combined array for every iteration from the outer foreach loop. The code is as follows:

```
data <- readLines('listofthings.txt') ##this is the master list
h <- as.vector(words(length=6,alphabet=s2c("ACGT"))) ##this is an array of six-lettered words that I want to search in data1 below

foreach (i = 1:length(data),.packages=c("ade4","seqinr")) %:% 
data1 <- s2c(c2s(data[i])) ##this converts the string to characters & is every item in the master 'data' list
g <- foreach (j = 1:length(data1),.packages=c("ade4","seqinr"),.combine=cbind) %dopar% {
  g[which(h==c2s(data1[j:(j+5)]))]+1 ##adds +1 to the same row which has the six letter word as h
}
```

So, I want the code to feed data1 into the inner loop and then carry out subsequent operations. I have written what every step does in the comments, and it may still be confusing. All I want to know is how to write a nested foreach loop such that the outer loop feeds the output of a function into the inner foreach loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` accepts data that it passes on in the first elements of the function arguments, "named" `...` in the help file of `?foreach`. These are the elements `foreach` iterates over. Below I create an example with a list that contains vectors, but those vectors can easily be data.frames, matrices or what-have-you.

```
library(foreach)

ml <- list(el1 = rnorm(10), el2 = rnorm(20), el3 = rnorm(30))

foreach(i = ml) %do% length(i)

[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] 20

[[3]]
[1] 30
```